# Why is my question put on hold?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about this: [How to change the default view of the "extend" page in a custom administration theme](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231390/how-to-change-the-default-view-of-the-extend-page-in-a-custom-administration-t)

Can you tell me why my question is put on hold or voted for closing ?

I think that my question is very clear with my screenshots and edited description that I have added.

I feel that as a new user asks a question you often ask to be closed or put on put on hold.

Can you check this case even for me ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm only guessing at the motivation for closing, but given the "Unclear what you're asking" I'd assume people aren't sure exactly what part of the desired feature you're stuck at implementing.

Writing broader tutorials/how-to's doesn't suit Q+A very well because there are often a bunch of different disciplines involved, different parts of the system to gain knowledge about, etc, so it's best to break a task down into smallest parts and ask questions about each of those. That way we end up with content that helps people who want to do a similar thing to you, but also helps people who need to solve the same generic tasks for another purpose altogether.

For example, if you're approaching this programatically your broken-down list of things to find out might be:

- How do I replace the content of an administration page, or create a new one?
- How can I make sure the permission requirements stay the same for the new/replaced page
- How do I programatically get a list of modules?
- How do I render that list into something pretty for the user?
- How do I get that rendered content onto the page?
- How do I achieve the layout I need while still allowing the form submission to operate?

I'm sure there are more but you get the idea.

I'm not saying you should necessarily ask all of these as questions, but those are the things you would go off and research, and when you get stuck with a narrower implementation detail, this site is the perfect medium to get help with it.

As an aside, there often *is* a, perhaps inevitable, correlation between the length of membership and likelihood of questions being closed. It's not because we don't want questions from new users, quite the opposite (we wouldn't survive without them), but because new users often aren't aware of the expectations put on them.

Writing a good question for this repository of knowledge is hard. It takes a lot of time and effort to properly research a topic and present a query in a way that's suitable for and useful to as broad an audience as possible; newer users are usually under the impression this is an extension of the drupal.org support forums, rather than [what it actually is](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tour).

There's no blame attached to that in any direction, we don't hold a grudge against anyone for asking a question that was deemed to be off-topic, but we do need to close them so they don't stick around and become examples for still newer users of what's acceptable to ask.

BTW those last few paragraphs (from the "aside") are much more general thoughts, I wasn't thinking about you or your question specifically when I wrote them.